# What SDK to install, seriously?

Tags: android

I know there are plenty of documents over the internet but I have still some doubts about what SDK to install on my computer to create an android application for nearly %100 devices to working with. Google Play says that if I use API 8 (which is Android 2.2) then my application work nearly all Android devices.

So I downloaded API 8 and API 22 (Android 5.1, was default installed by Android Studio itself) and I don't know if it works or not if I select Minimum SDK to API 8 while creating a new project.

So seriously guys, what the heck is going on?

Comment: Seeing minimum to 8 will work IIRC. Although be aware that developing for 2.2 is pretty damn hard. Consider targeting 2.3 or even 4.0.

Comment: What's the actual question? Doesn't your text already answer it? What do you mean, you don't know if it works?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know which API suits best for my application. My website is a kind of a social media website and my application is simply just going to connect to my website api and download contents, images and other things and a service for push notifications. Is API 8 is enough?

Comment: Is it? Does it do what you need it to? It has HTTP connections; it depends on what (and how) you want the app to actually *do*.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well yes. It will just append earlier posts while scrolling down and that's all.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're asking then, if you're saying it does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

What SDK Platform(s) you install has little to no impact on what versions of Android you can support.

If you create a new Android Studio project via the new-project wizard, you will find an `app/build.gradle` file. In there, you will find a setting named `compileSdkVersion`. This controls what version of the Android SDK you are compiling against (i.e., what JAR is used to satisfy compile-time references to Java classes like `Activity` and `TextView`). Whatever value you specify for `compileSdkVersion` must be an "SDK Platform" that you have installed from the SDK Manager.

In a newly-created project given your setup description from your question, you will see that `compileSdkVersion` is `22`, lining up with pre-established API Level 22 edition of the SDK Platform.

However, this does not mean that your app will only run on API Level 22+ devices. Much of what is in the API Level 22 edition of the Android SDK has existed in previous versions of the SDK.

The `minSdkVersion` property in the same `app/build.gradle` file says how old you are willing to go -- what is the lowest API level you are willing to support. Right now, I think a new project will be set up with `minSdkVersion` of 15, though that varies over time. More importantly, you can change it to be whatever you want, and you do not need the SDK Platform installed for whatever level you choose.

If, in your code, you reference stuff in the Android SDK that is valid for your `compileSdkVersion` but is newer than the `minSdkVersion`, the build tools will point out the discrepancy, so you can make sure that you know what you are doing. This is how Android handles progressive enhancement -- you see what version of Android you are running on (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`) and use newer APIs where you can, falling back to older APIs as needed.

TL;DR: So long as your `compileSdkVersion` has a value for which you have an installed SDK Platform, you're set.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application you are developing. And the resources that it will need. It's true that if you use the oldest version (API 8) and your application is simple enough, then it will work on any device.
But there are limitations to it. on older APIs you will not be able to use new features as Navigation drawer for example

I would recommend API 11 or 14, that covers most of the devices and features nowadays.

You should consider the design you want to create on your app

Comment: I don't actually need any advanced features. My application it will just append earlier posts while scrolling down and that's all as I said above and user will get notifications about things going on.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the market share of the different api versions here: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Then you have a trade-off of how advanced APIs you want to use vs. how many devices you want to support.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question.